# rails js method in all pages (link remote in layout) - filter chain halted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In layout file i have such code:

```
= link_to "city", set_city_path(city_id: 1), remote: true
```

and in controller:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def set_city_session
    if [1, 2, 3].include? params[:city_id].to_i
      session[:city_id] = params[:city_id].to_i
      @city_id = session[:city_id]
      render js: @city_id
    end
  end
end
```

in set_city_session.js.haml  i have

```
("#city-name-link").text("#{escape_javascript(render @city_id)}").hide().fadeIn('slow').focus();
```

and when i click on this link, in log i see, that

```
filter chain halted as :set_city_session rendered or redirected
```

but why? what i do wrong? and how to solve it?

Comment: `render js: @city_id` what are you trying to do with this?

Comment: @IshankGupta to change in layout some text: ("#city-name-link").text("#{escape_javascript(render @city_id)}")

Comment: @IshankGupta hem, this is haml man...  it's not the main problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of `render js: @city_id` from ArticlesController

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def set_city_session
    if [1, 2, 3].include? params[:city_id].to_i
      session[:city_id] = params[:city_id].to_i
      @city_id = session[:city_id]
    end
  end
end
```

And update your set_city_session.js.haml to

```
$("#city-name-link").text("#{escape_javascript(@city_id)}").hide().fadeIn('slow').focus();
```

Comment: just change ("#city-name-link"). to $("#city-name-link").